# How to check if there is a key pair of pairs?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    //freopen("text.txt" , "r",stdin);

    map<pair<pair<string,int>,pair<string,int>>,int>team;
    map<string,int>person1;
    map<string,int>person2;

    int n;
    string name1,name2;
    int score1,score2;
    cin >>n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> name1 >> score1 >> name2 >> score2;
        person1.insert(make_pair(name1,score1));
        person2.insert(make_pair(name2,score2));

        if(team.count(make_pair(person1,person2))) > 1)){
            
        }

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have a problem with `make_pair(person1,person2) > 0`. How can I check if there is a key pair of pairs?

Can you explain what I have to do?

Comment: read that line carefully. You put one `)` in the wrong place

Comment: Surely `map<pair<pair<string,int>,pair<string,int>>,int>` can be better represented by some kind of class/struct with better semantic meaning?

Comment: what is a bit strange is that you quote it including the typo as `make_pair(person1,person2) > 0` but I suppose you want `....count(...) > 0`

Comment: Why are you passing a `pair<map<string, int>, map<string, int>>` to `team.count`?